# elasticsearch: different results between _all and fields query string query

Tags: elasticsearch

When one doesn't specify fields for the query string query, then the `_all` field is used, that combines values from all fields that can be queried.

Q1: does elastic use the analyzer that was specified in the mapping for each field when creating the `_all` field?

Q2: if the answer to Q1 is yes, then I don't understand why I get different results between when specifying fields and when searching for `_all` fields.

My mapping looks like this:

```
settings: {
    analysis: {
        analyzer: {
            lowerCase: {
                tokenizer: 'whitespace',
                filter: ['lowercase']
            }
        }
    }
},
mappings: {
    entry: {
        properties: {
            id: { type: 'string' },
            type: { type: 'string', analyzer: 'lowerCase' },
            name: { type: 'string', analyzer: 'lowerCase' }
        }
    }
}
```

and I search for a specific doc that looks like:

```
{
    id: "id1",
    type: "SCRIPT",
    name: "X-Mark 90"
}
```

When I search for `+type:*SCRIPT* +name:*X\-Mark*`, I get the above document. However, when searching for `+*SCRIPT* +*X\-Mark*`, I get no results. I cannot understand why.

The es version we use is 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using the following mapping:

```
settings: {
    analysis: {
        analyzer: {
            lowerCase: {
                tokenizer: 'whitespace',
                filter: ['lowercase']
            }
        }
    }
},
mappings: {
    // used for _all field
    _default_: {
        index_analyzer: 'lowerCase'
    },
    entry: {
        properties: {
            id: { type: 'string', analyzer: 'lowerCase' },
            type: { type: 'string', analyzer: 'lowerCase' },
            name: { type: 'string', analyzer: 'lowerCase' }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about the analyzer of the

```
_all
```

field.

Your suggestion is that `_all` is a virtual field which search over all other fields. But _all is really a field in the lucene index: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-all-field.html

So the answer to Q1 is "no". Which means, that `type:*X-Mark*` 
does search for the substring "x-mark" in all tokens of field "type" but 
`*X-Mark*`does search for the phrase "*X Mark*". Because the default analyzer splits on "-". Possible 1.7 does not support wildcards in phrases...

So in your case you should set the analyzer of field `_all` to "lowerCase" and you will get what you expected.

In ES 5.X you can specify the analyzer on the same way as for every other fields.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/mapping-all-field.html

Possible it is the same for 1.7. You also could change the default-Analyzer.

Via "*default*"-Mapping:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/override-default-template.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/index-modules-mapper.html#_default_mapping

or via "default"-Analyzer
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/analyzer.html

Comment: I don't think this answers any of my 2 questions. And also, as I mentioned in the post, I'm using version 1.7

Comment: Yeah, I figured by trial and error that I had to also change the _default_ mapping for _all field